# How do i run a function only in debug mode in C with Code Block

Tags: c, codeblocks

if debugmode
    tester;
else
    Do not run the function

I tried to call it that way:
if debugmode = 0
    call the function

But it not work

Comment: Debug and release mode usually defines different macros that you can use for conditional compilation. I don't recommend it except to print or otherwise log extra information in a debug build. Doing other different things in debug versus release builds tend to make your program *harder* to debug.

Comment: The fact is that i want to run a bunch of functional tests but not in release mode

Comment: You can use "assert", no ?